# Colorbox and Image Resize

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I have a gallery where I want the User to Open a Picture with Colorbox. (Then send the Picture with a Mail or Print it etc.)

This Site must be programmed dynamically because it has to work on an IPad too.

Now to the actual Problem:

This div should be shown in the Colorbox:

```
<div style = "display:none"> 
 <div id="inline" style="height:100%; width:auto"> 
    <img src="#" id="inline_img" style="max-height:90%; max-width:100%"/> 
    <div id="buttons">
        <button > test </button>
        <button > test1 </button>
        <button > test2 </button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascripit function where the div opens up in the colorbox.

```
$(function(){
  //$('.element a').colorbox({});
  $('.element a').click(function(){
      // Using a selector:
    $('#inline_img').attr('src',$(this).find("img").attr('src'));
    $.fn.colorbox({
        inline:true,
        href:"#inline",
        maxHeight:'90%',
        maxWidth:'90%'
        }); 
    return false;
  });
  $('.element a').colorbox({    
        onComplete : function() { 
        $(this).colorbox.resize(); 
        }    
    });
```

But the Colorbox always is much bigger than the Picture itself. The Colorbox must be as big as the Image and in the center of the screen.

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 10):

I'm use the following code and resolve problem.

```
$('.colorBox').colorbox({
     scalePhotos: true,
     maxWidth: '100%'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That result makes sense to me.  You gave colorbox a display:block element with no defined width and asked it to estimate the size, which of course will be 100% of the available width.

Comment: sorry i didn't took the whole screen. it isn't 100% of the available width. it's just in the center of the screen with a random width.